# How to use mapserver on Android

Tags: android, mapserver

Can I use mapserver on Android? I want to make a standalone application with implementing tiling, zoom and pan. I need to manipulate .map file dynamically everytime. Can anyone suggest me how to take approach or how to use php mapscript to invoke mapserver?

Answer (score 1):

Mapserver is server side technology, it can be consumed by android or any other OS with a reasonable browser.

You need a server that will run Apache/Mapserver/PHP look at MS4w http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/

Comment: You can run servers as services on Android.

Comment: I didnt even imply that Android couldnt run it.  I was however pointing out that it doesnt need to and that it most likely shouldnt (unless you want to deploy a private local server for every install of your app)

Comment: Sometimes it's the only way if you want to use huge maps and be offline  (Internet connection is not always awailable). In fact this is the way how a lot of offline map applications are working - they have built-in web server running on localhost.

Answer (score -2):

Second that, MapServer is the GIS server side technology for you to publish your data to services. You will be able to consume the service all cross platform (most of them) via OGC standard protocal(e.g. WMS, WFS)

To invoke the service from MapServer, is as same as other services using http request. More details about how to consume services from MapServer: http://mapserver.org/ogc/wms_client.html